# Scrapy Custom ImagePipeline Settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written my own ImagePipeline for my scrapy project.  From my Googling I am getting different information about how to set the pipline in settings.py.

Let's say the pipeline is MyImagesPipeline and it exists in pipelines.py which contains:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

        some processing...
        return item
```

in my settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
    'myproject.pipelines.MyImagesPipeline': 100,
   }
```

I have two pipelines in there because if I put in MyImagesPipeline alone item_completed gets called but without any images and I get a KeyError because the field 'images' is not there. However, with both middlewares in the settings I am getting multiple copies of the same image.

Can someone please enlighten me on this?

EDIT:

The spider code is quite long because I am doing a lot of information processing in it but here are what I think might be the relevant parts (callback of parse):

```
def parse_data(self, response):
    img_urls = response.css('.product-image').xpath('.//img/@src').extract()
    img_url = img_urls[0]
    item['image_urls'] = [img_url,]
    yield item
```

Comment: did you check the yielded items? Does that contain multiple images?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  Here is an example:

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit return which sent the comment prematurely.  I tried to give an example but it was too long for a comment.  But the answer to your question is sometimes yes, sometimes no.  The 'image_urls' only has one image, (which is what I am sending),  But 'images' has multiple images with different urls.

Comment: could you please post your spider code ?

Comment: @user1127818 where is `item` instantiated?

Comment: There is parse, then a callback and the one I showed you is the callback after that one.  Item is instantiated in the callback after parse with item = MyProjectItem() which is declared as a class in items.py.  The MyProjectItem class has images = scrapy.Field(), image_urls = scrapy.Field()  and image_paths = scrapy.Field()

Answer (score 1):

Both image pipelines are processing the `images_urls` field in your items, that's why you're getting their images twice.

I'd try to stick with a single pipeline and fix any errors you encounter in it to get a self-contained component handling the whole image processing. Particularly, you have to deal better with the inheritance from `ImagesPipeline` to do so.

Regarding the KeyError, `ImagesPipeline.item_completed` method [is in charge of updating the `images` field in the items](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0.1/scrapy/pipelines/images.py#L113), if you override it it's not going to be available when you need it.

To fix that in your pipeline you can update it like this:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    ...

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        item = super(MyImagesPipeline, self).item_completed(results, item, info)

        some processing...
        return item
```

I recommend checking `ImagesPipeline`'s code (it's placed in [scrapy/pipelines/images.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0.1/scrapy/pipelines/images.py) in Scrapy 1.0 or [scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/0.24.6/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py) in previous versions but the code is practically the same) to fully understand what's going on inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Julia.  It sounds good but I finally gave up on Scrapy.  I am using Tornado.  It gives me more control.  I hope your answer helps someone else.